# Fraction number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a JavaScript project in which I need to display an array of numbers. This numbers can be integers or fractions. I need to display the fraction in the classic way, I mean, the top number, below a line and below the other number, as shown in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xW7d8/

The thing is that the array that I was talking about is the one that contains the numbers, and using Jquery I change the text of a div so I display the numbers, just like this:

97,30,58,53,42,60,77,11

69/90,10/32,74/74,9/54,69/2,17/86,62/72,55/85

First thing that I do is to fill the array, save the numbers to a string, and then, change the text of the div. Below is what I do in code:

```
var array = fillArray();//this fill an array of numbers, integers or fractions
var stringArray;//will contains the numbers of the array
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  stringArray+= array[i];
}
$("#num1").text(stringArray);
```

In this way, I cannot put a div ID to each number, if I try to do this its not interpreted as HTML, what I take is the text of the HTML tag itself, for example, for the number 1/2 if I try to do:

```
<span class="fraction">1/2</span>
```

I literally get the span class, it is not read as HTML code.

I tried also to generate the format for the fraction in the JavaScript code itself doing this:

```
var number = x + "\n" + "-" + "\n" + y;
```

This do not work, it don't recognize the "\n", neither "\r", etc (if I try with < br/ > is written literally)

Is there some way to get the fraction numbers the way I want? Probably I will need to generate the number in this format in the JavaScript itself without the help of the HTML tags.

Comment: Have you consider a library like http://www.mathjax.org/? May not be what you are looking for / to heavy weight / not a good solution but its hard for me to tell and I just though i'd put it out there.

Comment: The `\n` doesn't work because you are putting out HTML (or just text). In HTML those characters are just a backslash followed by an 'n'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with the string containing the tags. It should begin with a tag, though:

```
$("#num1").html(stringArray);
```

But since your fiddle rewrites the div with the fraction class you probably just want to generate the whole html of the fractions yourself. `<span class="top">1</span><span class="bottom">2</span>` instead of doing the `<span class='fraction'>1/2</span>` and then running the code to convert.

Comment: This is right. When you do `$("#num1").text(stringArray)` all the HTML is interpreted as text, converted to entities rather than HTML. So you should do `$("#num1").html(stringArray)` instead since you are wanting to specify HTML data instead of plain text.

Comment: The $("#num1").html(stringArray) worked, now I have the span class identified as HTML, however, I'm not sure where to put the JavaScript code of the Fiddle to make this run. I tried to put it on $(document).ready but it didn't work. Where I need to put this code?

Comment: Don't use it. Generate the HTML in the stringArray variable itself. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to use JQuery's html() function instead of text()

```
$("#num1").html(stringArray);
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, in fact I'm close to resolve the problem. Please see the comment that I left in the above answer. Thanks for taking the time to answer.